# converting one d list to 2d lists(writing error)

Tags: python

so im doing input/output and i was trying to get the logic of my program down, being that given names and courses, i would write to the file the names in alphabetical order, followed by the courses they took. i accomplished that and wrote everything to a one d list in the progress. now im trying to wrtie to a text file `"name, class, .....(if more than one class)"`
but since i have made it into a 1d list the program writes item by item and not names and classes groped together. ex, i want the new file to read

```
Ashley,MATH 1426,PHYS 1443
Jonathan,IE 3312
Joseph,IE 3312
Nang,MATH 1426
Ram,IE 3312
Randal,IE 3301,MATH 2325,PHYS 1443
Sol,IE 3301
```

how do i do this if i have a one d list. i was thinking of writing something like

```
while name, remains the same, write the classes, when name changes print newline....., write name and classes
```

problem with this is its a oned list and im not sure how to detect a name change. Is there anyway to convert this into a 2dlist each sublist containing one name and its classes? here is my original 2d list in its unorginzed form,

```
[['Adam', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ashley', 'IE 3312'], ['Ashley', 'PHYS 1443'], ['August', 'PHYS 1444'], ['Baron', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Christopher', 'IE 3301'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1320'], ['Christopher', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1310'], ['Henry', 'PHYS 1444'], ['James', 'IE 3301'], ['James', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'IE 3312'], ['Krishna', 'CSE 1310'], ['Luis', 'CSE 1310'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Pramod', 'PHYS 1444'], ['Pramod', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Saroj', 'IE 3301'], ['Saroj', 'MATH 1426'], ['Sol', 'CSE 1310'], ['Timothy', 'MATH 2325'], ['Timothy', 'IE 3301']]
```

to orginize i wrote the following code, appending it to a list which was a mistake

```
d = []
size = len(c)
two = []
d.append(c[0][0])
d.append(c[0][1])
i = 1
while i < size  :
    # if current name = previous name, add classes
    if c[i][0]==c[i-1][0] :
        d.append(c[i][1])  
    # if current name != previous name, add name and classes
    if c[i][0]!= c[i-1][0] :
        d.append(c[i][0])
        d.append(c[i][1])
    i = i + 1
```

output was

```
['Adam', 'PHYS 1443', 'Ashley', 'IE 3312', 'PHYS 1443', 'August', 'PHYS 1444', 'Baron', 'PHYS 1443', 'Christopher', 'IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443', 'Dylan', 'CSE 1310', 'Henry', 'PHYS 1444', 'James', 'IE 3301', 'PHYS 1443', 'Jonathan', 'IE 3312', 'Krishna', 'CSE 1310', 'Luis', 'CSE 1310', 'Michael', 'IE 3301', 'Nang', 'PHYS 1443', 'Pramod', 'PHYS 1444', 'PHYS 1443', 'Saroj', 'IE 3301', 'MATH 1426', 'Sol', 'CSE 1310', 'Timothy', 'MATH 2325', 'IE 3301']
```

is there any easy fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
print [[key, [cls[1] for cls in list(group)]]
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

**Output**

```
[['Adam', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Ashley', ['IE 3312', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['August', ['PHYS 1444']],
 ['Baron', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Christopher', ['IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Dylan', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Henry', ['PHYS 1444']],
 ['James', ['IE 3301', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Jonathan', ['IE 3312']],
 ['Krishna', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Luis', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Michael', ['IE 3301']],
 ['Nang', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Pramod', ['PHYS 1444', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Saroj', ['IE 3301', 'MATH 1426']],
 ['Sol', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Timothy', ['MATH 2325', 'IE 3301']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.groupby() like @thefourtheye or a defaultdict to organize by names :

```
from collections import defaultdict
>>> onedlist = zip(["ADAM","JOHN"]*5,range(10))
[('ADAM', 0), ('JOHN', 1), ('ADAM', 2), ('JOHN', 3), ('ADAM', 4), ('JOHN', 5), ('ADAM', 6), ('JOHN', 7), ('ADAM', 8), ('JOHN', 9)]
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for name,val in onedlist: my_dict[name].append(val)
>>> print my_dict["ADAM"]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to convert it to a dictionary instead:

```
d = {}
for k,v in l: #l is your list
    if d[k]:
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = v
```

Output:

```
{'Krishna': ['CSE 1310'], 'Dylan': ['CSE 1310'], 'Ashley': ['IE 3312', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Baron': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Timothy': ['MATH 2325', 'IE 3301'], 'James': ['IE 3301', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Pramod': ['PHYS 1444', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Michael': ['IE 3301'], 'Sol': ['CSE 1310'], 'Nang': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Christopher': ['IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Adam': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Henry': ['PHYS 1444'], 'Saroj': ['IE 3301', 'MATH 1426'], 'Luis': ['CSE 1310'], 'Jonathan': ['IE 3312'], 'August': ['PHYS 1444']}
```

And then, printing it:

```
>>> for k,v in d.items(): #iterates through d
    print(k, end=' ')
    for i in v:
        print (i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Krishna CSE 1310 
Dylan CSE 1310 
Ashley IE 3312 PHYS 1443 
Baron PHYS 1443 
Timothy MATH 2325 IE 3301 
James IE 3301 PHYS 1443 
Henry PHYS 1444 
Michael IE 3301 
Sol CSE 1310 
Nang PHYS 1443 
August PHYS 1444 
Christopher IE 3301 CSE 1320 PHYS 1443 
Adam PHYS 1443 
Pramod PHYS 1444 PHYS 1443 
Luis CSE 1310 
Saroj IE 3301 MATH 142
```

Storing it in a dictionary is also much faster and efficient than storing it in a multi-dimensional array. Take a look at this:

```
>>> timeit("""[['Adam', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Ashley', ['IE 3312', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['August', ['PHYS 1444']],
 ['Baron', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Christopher', ['IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Dylan', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Henry', ['PHYS 1444']],
 ['James', ['IE 3301', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Jonathan', ['IE 3312']],
 ['Krishna', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Luis', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Michael', ['IE 3301']],
 ['Nang', ['PHYS 1443']],
 ['Pramod', ['PHYS 1444', 'PHYS 1443']],
 ['Saroj', ['IE 3301', 'MATH 1426']],
 ['Sol', ['CSE 1310']],
 ['Timothy', ['MATH 2325', 'IE 3301']]]""")
5.6225116937032311
>>> timeit("""{'Krishna': ['CSE 1310'], 'Dylan': ['CSE 1310'], 'Ashley': ['IE 3312', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Baron': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Timothy': ['MATH 2325', 'IE 3301'], 'James': ['IE 3301', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Pramod': ['PHYS 1444', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Michael': ['IE 3301'], 'Sol': ['CSE 1310'], 'Nang': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Christopher': ['IE 3301', 'CSE 1320', 'PHYS 1443'], 'Adam': ['PHYS 1443'], 'Henry': ['PHYS 1444'], 'Saroj': ['IE 3301', 'MATH 1426'], 'Luis': ['CSE 1310'], 'Jonathan': ['IE 3312'], 'August': ['PHYS 1444']}
""")
3.4978408664244967
```